# How to add java library without no repository to pom file?

Tags: java, maven

I'd like to add one project A as my dependency, but unfortunately, there's no repository host this library. I know that I can install it to local repository manually, then refer this in pom file. But I have a travis build job where there's no such artifact, is there any way that I can install this library to local repo automatically ? Thanks

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: Do an install to your local .m2 in a command shell using the mvn command.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use the clean approach and uploading this library into your own repository. If you don't have one: time to get one running.

If you're really not up to this task the maven install plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html can install a jar in the local repository. This will work both locally and on a CI server.

To upload a jar in a remote repository there is the deploy plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html

If you bind the execution of this plugin to a very early phase in the [maven life-cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) (validate) you might be able to avoid a build step required prior of your own build.